# Convert line into columns using pivot

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, pivot

I aim to turn rows of this table into columns.

This is my table:

```sql
 select  tipoDocumento_id,nome,resultado
  from Campos

tipoDocumento_id nome                           resultado
---------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
62               Data:                          2019-05-20                    
62               N.I.F. fornecedor:             501062327                     
62               Total:                         31,14                         
62               Número fatura:                 FT19/04006                    
63               Data:                          2019-05-23                    
63               N.I.F. fornecedor:             501062327                     
63               Total:                         39,14                         
63               Número fatura:                 FT19/04007
```

For now I have this query but it's returning NULL

```sql
select Data,NIF , Total, Numero fatura
from
(
  select  tipoDocumento_id,nome,resultado
  from Campos
) d
pivot
(
  max(tipoDocumento_id)
  for resultado in (Data,NIF , Total, Numero fatura)
) piv;
```

Probably my bad it´s on aggregating with `max()`

I want a result like that

```
ID    Data:          N.I.F. fornecedor:    Total:      Número fatura:
62    2019-05-20     501062327             31,14       FT19/04006
63    2019-05-23     501062327             39,14       FT19/04007
```

Can someone give me a little help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were circling around it

```
select *
from
(
  select id=tipoDocumento_id
        ,nome
        ,resultado
  from Campos
) d
pivot
(
  max(resultado)
  for nome in ([Data:],[N.I.F. fornecedor:],[Total:],[Número fatura:])
) piv;
```

Comment: I still do the case statement over the pivot

Comment: @KeithL Assuming you mean the conditional aggregation...  Each method has pros and cons.   It seems like OP was looking for the syntax of pivot.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti One more question pls, is it possible create multiple lines with same ID? like, instead I have ID nº 62 and 63, I have all lines with ID 62. Is it possible using PIVOT?

Comment: @danLopes Not clear.  Filter on ID or multiple rows for ID.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti like in my question, but in this case I have all lines with `tipoDocumento_id` with value 62 and i want two lines as result like in my question

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was talking about with using a case statement instead of pivot (not looking for you to change answer, just giving another option):

```
 select  tipoDocumento_id
     ,max(case when nome = 'Data:' then resultado else null end) as [Data:]          
     ,max(case when nome = 'N.I.F. fornecedor:' then resultado else null end) as [N.I.F. fornecedor:]
     ,max(case when nome = 'Total:' then resultado else null end) as [Total:]
     ,max(case when nome ='Número fatura:' then resultado else null end) as [Número fatura:]
  from Campos
group by tipoDocumento_id
```

Comment: Thank you, it's an alternative too :), but imagine like in my question, I have all lines with `tipoDocumento_ID` equals to  62, and i want the same result but instead of second line with 63, I want 62 too. Is that possible? Thank you

Comment: i don't understand your goal. can you update your expected results.

Comment: as it is now. is it possible to do using the pivot? Thanks

Comment: the way you change your source would yield 1 row result. I don't think your source should have changed but I am not in control of that

Comment: it's just an example, because i have to do it in another table. But thanks anyway